# upgrading VSIX from VS 2013 to VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, vsix, vsixmanifest

I have created a Visual Studio extension(vsix) in VS 2013 to add a new Project Template. I need to make it working in VS 2015. I have modified source.extension.vsixmanifest file to include Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro[14.0]. The problem is it is getting installed in VS 2015, but there are some VS 2013 specific dlls. So it is giving errors while creating project. Is there any way to make it working in VS 2015, without rewriting the entire code.?

Comment: Which dlls are specific to VS 2013? The devenv.exe.config file of each VS version has <bindingRedirect> elements to use the new versions of the dlls.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

1. Open your project with VS2015
2. Right click and select add, new item
3. In Visual C# Items, choose Extensibility
4. Add a VSPackage.cs item
5. Remove each references to this package if you don't need it

Visual studio will add new references for VS2015. This is not a perfect solution and it may not compile because you have a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0 so just remove it.

Let me know if you need more help but it should be a good start.